# Queries on 'All subscribers' attributes in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, subscriber

I have an attribute called CardId in my all subscribers list and want to query it, but I get the following error if I do so: `"The query syntax is invalid" Invalid column name 'CardId'`.

This is the query I tried to execute:

```
Select CardId from _subscribers
```

Is it correct that I can't use attributes other than the standard ones from the _dataview table in a query activity?

My workaround solution would be to export the all subscribers list (1.3 million rows), import them into a data extension and then query this data extension. But that seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Ohhh. I cant even export a list automaticly, only a DE...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the account is an Enterprise 2.0 account, you can query Profile Attributes by accessing the `_EnterpriseAttribute` data view.

[Data View: EnterpriseAttribute](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_enterpriseattribute/)

Simply do a join onto the `_EnterpriseAttribute` table, and you'll have access to all of your fields.

Comment: And if it's not enterprise? (Not sure if it is)

Comment: I believe you're out of luck query-wise on this one. Would a filter work to create a Group for your use case?

Comment: I need to join some other DE as well, so unfortunately groups dosnt do it :-(

Comment: If it's not an E2 account, you can always get the Attributes into a DE via Tracking Data Extract and import.  It's a pain, but it can be done.

Comment: Is there a way to access data in the _EnterpriseAttribute table using ampscript?

Comment: Yes - it works as you might expect - you just need the Subscriber ID value. Ex: SET @FirstName = Lookup("_EnterpriseAttribute", "FirstName", "_SubscriberID", SubscriberID). Keep in mind just like a query it only works at parent level.