# Extract Attributes in a Data Extract not showing up

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've created a Data Extract Activity and have Extract Attributes set to True, but I am not getting an 'Attributes.csv' file within the zip folder. The [documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/attributes/) states...

> This extract only outputs data for subscribers who received one of these events over the specified time:
>
> - Bounce
> - Click
> - FTAF
> - Open
> - Send
> - Survey
> - Unsubscribe

Does this mean that one of these Extract fields must be True in order for the Attributes.csv to actually run and appear?

I'm trying to keep the zip folder size as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd answer this since I found the answer, in case anyone else stumbles upon it.

Essentially the way it works is, the only subscribers that get exported and added to the Attributes.csv file are those found in the the results of the other extracts listed above. So, there isn't a way to export all subscribers attributes on it's own via an extract, unless you did something very generic that would include everyone, like everyone sent an email in the last 90 days, or something.

I think the better way to do this is with a query and a file transfer though. [This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/queries-on-all-subscribers-attributes-in-marketing-cloud/) shows you how to do that.